# Command-line input with Sys.stdin() not working in Haxe

Tags: command-line, haxe

I'm trying to use the input function from the `Sys` class, but when I run the build and the prompt occurs, I'm unable to enter any input. What alternatives are there to `Sys`, or what ought I do to resolve this? I've checked Haxelib and haven't found anything that I think can be used.

For reference, what I have written:

```
Sys.println("First player's name: ");
var p1:String = Sys.stdin().readLine();
```

My hxml args:

```
-main Main.hx
-cp src
-cp src/cards
-cp src/cards/library
-lib Random
-neko test.n
-cmd neko test.n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine if you manually start the generated `test.n` instead of doing that via `-cmd` in the hxml. I suspect that the Haxe process does not direct input to the stdin of the `-cmd` process or something like that.

If you still want to compile and run at the same time, I recommend creating a little `.bat` (or `.sh` if you're on Linux) script for this:

```
haxe build.hxml
neko test.n
```